# Amazon Web Services - EC2 - Active Directory (Domain Controller) | Web Server (IIS) | DB Server (SQL Server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-vpc

I would like to setup 3 Windows 2012R2 EC2 instances:

1. AD Server (Domain Controller)
2. Web Server (IIS)
3. Database Server (SQL Server)

Setting up the servers individually is fine, but I would like to setup the AD Server so that it acts as a Domain Controller. I would just like the domain to run in the cloud, it is not necessary that the Domain be accessible from a remote office.

I have tried setting up the AD Server by installing the Windows feature. That part is working fine, however, when I try setting a static IP, then I lose complete access to the machine. Note when installing AD I have installed DHCP and DNS as well. The configuration is where I am getting stuck.

Can anyone advise / point me to a good tutorial on setting up an architecture like this in AWS EC2? I am developer who striving to better under dev ops.

Comment: Asking for on-line resources is off-topic here. In any case, your question is about server configuration and this is a programming site so it's off topic for that reason too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: My apologies for not following the rules.  However I hope the link listed below by @eug will be useful to some one else in the future.  Is it possible to reword the question in order to save my reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a static IP on the domain controller, instead try allocating an Elastic IP for it. Amazon's docs include a guide to setting up a DC: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ConfigWindowsHPC.html

Comment: no prob, glad you found it useful!